# How to match anything except space and new line?

Tags: python, regex

I have a string, I just want to match substring for any character(s) except for space and new line. What should be regular expression for this?

I know regular expressions for anything but space i.e. `[^ ]+` and regular expression for anything but new line `[^\n]+` (I'm on Windows). I am not able to figure it out how to club them together.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can add the space character to your character class to be excluded.

```
^[^\n ]*$
```

Regular expression

```
^              # the beginning of the string
 [^\n ]*       # any character except: '\n' (newline), ' ' (0 or more times)
$              # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

Answer (score 11):

**Try this**

```
[^\s]+
```

\s is shorthand for whitespaces i.e space( ), newline (\n), tab (\t).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to exclude just space and newline characters, then you might want to use

```
r'^[^ \n]*$'
```

For example,

```
print re.match(r'^[^ \n]*$', """WelcometoStackoverflow""")
# <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f77a2a58238>
print re.match(r'^[^ \n]*$', """Welcome toStackoverflow""")
# None
print re.match(r'^[^ \n]*$', """Welcome
toStackoverflow""")
# None
```

Note that it will not eliminate all the other whitespace characters, like tabs, line feed characters etc

```
print re.match(r'^[^ \n]*$', """Welcome\ttoStackoverflow""")
# <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f77a2a58238>
```

So if you want to exclude all the whitespace characters then you can use

```
r'^[^\s]*$'
```

Or

```
r'^\S*$'
```

For example,

```
print re.match(r'^[^\s]*$', """WelcometoStackoverflow""")
# <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x7f9146c8b238>
print re.match(r'^[^\s]*$', """Welcome toStackoverflow""")
# None
print re.match(r'^[^\s]*$', """Welcome
toStackoverflow""")
# None
print re.match(r'^[^\s]*$', """Welcome\ttoStackoverflow""")
# None
```

`\S` is the same as `[^\s]`. Quoting from the docs,

> #### \s
>
> When the `UNICODE` flag is not specified, it matches any whitespace character, this is equivalent to the set `[ \t\n\r\f\v]`. The `LOCALE` flag has no extra effect on matching of the space. If `UNICODE` is set, this will match the characters `[ \t\n\r\f\v]` plus whatever is classified as space in the Unicode character properties database.
>
> #### \S
>
> When the `UNICODE` flags is not specified, matches any non-whitespace character; this is equivalent to the set `[^ \t\n\r\f\v]` The `LOCALE` flag has no extra effect on non-whitespace match. If `UNICODE` is set, then any character not marked as space in the Unicode character properties database is matched.

Comment: 'WelcometoStackoverflow' ---> don't think so, OP is 1 year and 7 months old user, I am too ;)

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Couldn't think of anything else :)

Comment: Symptoms Of Addiction to SO :P