# Regex validation: Allow new lines but not spaces

Tags: regex, validation

I know there are loads of questions on this site around regex and validating against white spaces, believe me I've spent the past few hours looking. I've been unable to create a regex validation that matches the following requirements:

- Fail validation if there are any spaces in this text (including at the start and end of the text)
- Allow validation if the text has new lines in it

I very quickly found /s was not a good option as this fails on my second point. The closest I've managed to get is `[A-Z]*[a-z]*[\" *"$]` which flags exactly the reverse (spaces pass but everything else fails).

I've tried reversing it somehow but not having much success.

Comment: Maybe `^[^ ]+$`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/23235232/3832970, this is what could help you right away, just remove `\n`

Comment: @downvoter Any comments? Duplicate != poorly asked question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anchor to the beginning of the string, repeatedly match anything but a space with `[^ ]*`, and anchor to the end of the string:

```
^[^ ]*$
```

This matches 0 or more non-space characters, but will permit newlines. (If you want 1 or more non-space characters, use `+` instead of `*`)

Comment: Thought it might be something simple.... Thank you very much! Saved hours of headache!